# convert number index of string array to double array

Tags: c#

I am reading from a text file, pulling each line, looking for the first line with 1|, and then converting it into an array. For this I only want the 4th index so that I can sum and count the array.

Here is what is converts from the text file into an array
1|123456|01/06/2019|123456|100.00|USD|DUE UPON RECEIPT|TEST1||98790125|TEST2|TEST3|N

so [0] = 1, [2] = 123456, etc. etc. I am trying to pull 100.00 from it and put it in it's own array, so that I can easily double sum, and count the elements. It's proving difficult for me since the original array is a string though.

I've tried creating a separate string array already split, and then pulling the 4th index and creating an double array that I can count and sum. I've also tried just splitting and creating an int array in one line from the str it pulls.

```
        string str;
        using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader("c:\\testdoc.txt"))
            while ((str = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] strArray = str.Split('|');
                if (strArray[0] == "1")
                {
                    double[] itotals = strArray.Select(i => Convert.ToDouble(i)).ToArray();
                    int count = itotals.Length;
                    double amt = itotals.Sum();
                    Console.WriteLine("Count: " + count + " Amt: " + amt);
                }
                else
                {
                }
            }
```

I expect it to find the line starting with 1|, then tell console to write count: 1 amt: 100.00, but I actually just get errors that input strings were not in the correct format. I know that I need to pull the 4th index after I split, but I'm not sure where to do that.

Comment: Have you tried with `tryparse`? https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ew0seb73(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: On your 8th line, you're trying to convert *everything* to a double. Just grab the index you're looking for and convert that instead - or else use a TryParse to only catch the ones that succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
string str;
        int count = 0;
        double amt = 0;
        using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader("c:\\testdoc.txt"))
            while ((str = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] strArray = str.Split('|');
                if (strArray[0] == "1")
                {
                    string itotals = strArray[4];
                    count = count+1;
                    amt = amt + Convert.ToDouble(strArray[4]);
                    Console.WriteLine("Count: " + count + " Amt: " + amt);
                }
                else
                {
                }
            }
```

Comment: This works, but my text file actually has multiple lines in it, so console is outputting each line and amt individually, continuously adding them until it reaches the last line. The last line is exactly how I want it, but I am more so looking for one output in total. Guessing I just need to place the output outside the loop with an if statement that if count != 0 then to output?

Comment: Sure, just put the Console.WriteLine after the while statement.  Then you will just get the final output